# htaccess redirect for new app

Tags: .htaccess

I'm migrating an existing application to a new codebase, but I want some of the existing links to work.

Basically I have affiliates that POST data to a link on my site ( link is : apply/affiliate/leadcheck )

The data they post is  : first_name surname dob etc

Anyhow on the new codebase this leadcheck will be accessed elsewhere (like index.php?mod=leadcheck).

Is there any way to ensure that any POST requests to apply/affiliate/leadcheck will be redirected to index.php?mod=leadcheck ?

Answer (score 0):

Redirect POST requests to a fixed link

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} post [NC]
RewriteRule ^apply/affiliate/leadcheck index.php?mod=leadcheck
```